# How to display error message and stop macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a novice at coding VBA. I want to add a pop up box with the message "Today's date not found" and stop the macro if today's date is not found in column K. Not sure how to go about this and where the code should be.

```
' Find the last row on the count sheet and the next row on the archieve sheet

lastRow = countSheet.Cells(countSheet.Rows.count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
nextRow = archieveSheet.Cells(countSheet.Rows.count, "K").End(xlUp).Row + 1

' Look at all rows in the count sheet
For thisRow = 1 To lastRow

    ' Check if column K contains today's date
    If countSheet.Cells(thisRow, "K").Value = Date Then

        ' Copy the entire row to the archieve sheet
        countSheet.Cells(thisRow, "K").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=archieveSheet.Cells(nextRow, "A")

        ' Move to the next row on the archieve sheet
        nextRow = nextRow + 1
    End If
Next thisRow
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding some simple code at the beginning would keep everything simple

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(countsheet.Range("K:K"), Date) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Today's Date Not Found"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: This! Guard clauses FTW! Fail early, bail out fast - reduces nesting and keeps the "happy path" focused on doing its thing. :+1:

Comment: i am now getting an error: Object variable or block variable not set

Comment: @JamieB on which line?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
'Create a new boolean variable for keeping track of if the date has been found
Dim bDateFound As Boolean

'Set that boolean to false to begin with (this step is optional, it will be False by default if not defined)
bDateFound = False
lastRow = countSheet.Cells(countSheet.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
nextRow = archieveSheet.Cells(countSheet.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row + 1

' Look at all rows in the count sheet
For thisRow = 1 To lastRow

    ' Check if column K contains today's date
    If countSheet.Cells(thisRow, "K").Value = Date Then
        'Add line here because a date was found to set your boolean variable to true
        bDateFound = True

        ' Copy the entire row to the archieve sheet
        countSheet.Cells(thisRow, "K").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=archieveSheet.Cells(nextRow, "A")

        ' Move to the next row on the archieve sheet
        nextRow = nextRow + 1
    End If
Next thisRow

'After your loop, put in a check to see if the date was found
If bDateFound = False Then
    'If the boolean is still false, then it was never found
    'Display a msgbox containing your error
    MsgBox "Today's date not found. Exiting macro.", , "Error"
    Exit Sub    'Exit the macro
End If

'If the date was found, then the code will continue here
```

Comment: @JamieB see the other alternative answer for that.